# Example of (not necessarily compactly supported) Hölder continuous wavelet?

Tags: fourier-analysis, wavelets

In Chapter six of “Ten lectures on wavelets” Daubechies presents a construction of compactly supported Hölder continuous wavelets. However, it seems that those wavelets cannot be represented by some more or less explicit analytic expression. I was wondering whether there are Hölder continuous wavelets not having compact support that can be expressed explicitly?

Comment: Sure, there are even differentiable wavelets - one class are wavelets defined via splines. If I remember correctly, they are also treated in Daubechies book. Also, it depends on the type of wavelets you are looking  for. If you are interested in the continuous wavelet transform, any function for which $\int \frac{|\hat \psi(x)|^2}{|x|}dx$ is finite is a wavelet. If you are looking for orthogonal wavelets, that's a different matter.

Comment: The Meyer wavelet (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meyer_wavelet) should do what you want.